# select top 1 per group and transform

Tags: sql

I've got column "stopNumber" in a table called action. The stop numbers contain a sequence of stops for a route where some stops represent pickups (defined in column action kind: action kind "pickup"; action kind "delivery") and other stops represent deliveries. Stop numbers can repeat if they're for the same customer
Example:

| id_action | stopNumber | actionKind |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | pickup |
| 2 | 2 | pickup |
| 3 | 3 | delivery |
| 4 | 3 | delivery |
| 5 | 4 | delivery |
| 6 | 5 | delivery |
| 7 | 5 | delivery |

However, my customer wants me to exclude the pickups from the stopNumber sequence and have the first delivery be stopNumber 1. Expected result:

| id_action | stopNumber | actionKind | newStopNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | pickup | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | pickup | NULL |
| 3 | 3 | delivery | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | delivery | 1 |
| 5 | 4 | delivery | 2 |
| 6 | 5 | delivery | 3 |
| 7 | 5 | delivery | 3 |

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you even tried anything at all???

Answer (score 0):

One option uses window functions and conditional expressions:

```
select t.*,
    case when actionkind <> 'pickup' 
        then dense_rank() over(
            partition by case when actionkind <> 'pickup' then 0 else 1 end
            order by stopnumber
        ) 
    end as newtopnumber
from mytable t
```